# align-items: center, with label and input element

Tags: html, css

A part of my React code looks like this

```
<div className="register-input-row">
            <label className="register-label" htmlFor="name">Name</label>
            <input className="register-input" type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={(e) => {
              this.setState({
                name: e.target.value
              });
            }}/>
          </div>
```

And I want to align the children of .register-input-row **vertically**, but when in the css I say `display: flex; align-items: center;` that just ends up pushing the label and input left. What can I do to center the children?

Comment: Can you paste the ("*[mcve]*" code) that's generated by the React script rather than just this snippet of React?

Comment: You should use `flex-direction:column;`

Comment: Please read about [the axes of Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#the_main_axis) and how they affect properties like `align-items` and `justify-content`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Center horizontally to retain original position as well as vertical:

```
.register-input-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `flex-direction:column`.

```css
div {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<div className="register-input-row">
<label className="register-label" htmlFor="name">Name</label>
<input className="register-input" type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={(e)=> { this.setState({ name: e.target.value }); }}/>
</div>
```